# How to select the option File from menu as per the html provided?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

I'm trying to do automation and struck in the middle.
Cannot able to select option from a submenu.

Tried every solution from stack overflow and anything doesn't work.

Attaching the code.

```
<input id="arid_WIN_0_2000053" class="text " readonly="" style="top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 72px; height: 21px;" title="Screen" type="text">
```

This is the id i need to click so a drop down appears.

That is from differant section and the code is,

```
<table class="MenuTable" style="width: 93px;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
   <tbody class="MenuTableBody">
      <tr class="MenuTableRow">
         <td class="MenuEntryName" nowrap="">Screen</td>
         <td class="MenuEntryNoSub" arvalue="Screen"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="MenuTableRow">
         <td class="MenuEntryName" nowrap="">File</td>
         <td class="MenuEntryNoSub" arvalue="File"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="MenuTableRow">
         <td class="MenuEntryName" nowrap="">Printer</td>
         <td class="MenuEntryNoSub" arvalue="Printer"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="MenuTableRow">
         <td class="MenuEntryNameHover" nowrap="">(clear)</td>
         <td class="MenuEntryNoSubHover" arvalue=""></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Once i selected the ID `arid_WIN_0_2000053`, i need to select option as File.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Replace the `{` with the original **`<`** for the volunteers to interpret the HTML correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the *HTML* to select an option e.g. **File** from the submenu you can use either of the following solutions:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='text' and @title='Screen'][starts-with(@id,'arid_WIN_0_')]").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@class='MenuTable']//tr[@class='MenuTableRow']//td[@class='MenuEntryName' and contains(.,'File')]").click()
```

Or

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='text' and @title='Screen'][starts-with(@id,'arid_WIN_0_')]").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@class='MenuTable']//tr[@class='MenuTableRow']//td[@class='MenuEntryNoSub' and @arvalue='File']").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use as Css locator : `.MenuTableRow:nth-of-type(2) .MenuEntryName`